# delimeter in String.Join()

Tags: java

Syntax for String.join((CharSequence delimiter,
                          Iterable elements))

Well the delimeter I want to use is **','** . Automatically it is getting read as simple comma (**,**). Can anybody help me with the situation?

Statement I have written is as follows:

> String helper = "**a,b**";
>   String temp = "','";
>
> helper.replaceAll(",",temp);

After the replace statement, the value of helper is still "**a,b**".
Expected value of helper in "**a','b**"

NOTE: Even masking in not helping eg

> helper.replaceAll("\',\'",temp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works, but the String is immutable. The method [replaceAll(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) returns the new String itself with replacement and you need to assign it to a variable.

```
String helper = "a,b"; 
String temp = "','";
helper = helper.replaceAll(",",temp);
```